# JTable, как сделать редактируемой и как копировать инф в textArea

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Приветствую!
Вопрос относительно JTable и кнопки. isCellEditable -true имеется, но таблица остается не редактируемой. И как можно реализовать кнопку, копирующую информацию из таблицы в textArea в том же виде. т.е.:
one     two three   four
five    six seven   eight
nine    ten eleven  twelve
Код:

```
    public class Table extends JFrame{                                             
    Table(){
        class DataModel extends AbstractTableModel {
            Object [][] data = {{"one","two","three", "four"},
                    {"five","six","seven","eight"},
                    {"nine","ten","eleven","twelve"}                                
            };
            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return data.length;
            }
            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return data[0].length;
            }
            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int i, int i1) {
                return data[i][i1];
            }
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int i,int i1){
                return true;
            }
            public Object setValueAt(int i, int i1){
                return data[i][i1];
            }
        };
        JButton button = new JButton("Change data");
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("PLACE FOR TEXT ");

        DataModel varModel = new DataModel();
        JTable table = new JTable(varModel);

        JPanel panelForTable = new JPanel();
        JPanel panelOther = new JPanel();

        add(panelForTable);
        add(panelOther,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        //getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(panelMain));               //
        panelForTable.add(table);
        panelOther.add(textArea);
        panelOther.add(button);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        class Button implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                //code for btn
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Table();
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас не переопределен `setValueAt(Object, int, int)`, поэтому не редактируется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По итогу рабочий вариант такой

```
   public class Table extends JFrame{
    Object [][] data = {{"one","two","three", "four"},
                        {"five","six","seven","eight"},
                        {"nine","ten","eleven","twelve"}
    };
    String [] columnNames = {"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4", };
    Object [][] dataForSecondTable = new Object[data.length][data.length];
    Table(){
        class DataModel extends AbstractTableModel {
            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return data.length;
            }
            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return data[0].length;
            }
            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int i, int i1) {
                return data[i][i1];
            }
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int i,int i1){
                return true;
            }
            public Object setValueAt(int i, int i1){
                return data[i][i1];
            }
        };
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(4,15);
        class ButtonAction implements ActionListener {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < data[0].length; j++) {
                        textArea.append(data[i][j]+" ");
                    }
                    textArea.append("\n");
                }
            }
        }
        JButton button = new JButton("Change data");
        ButtonAction buttonAction = new ButtonAction();
        button.addActionListener(buttonAction);

        JTable table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
        JTable table2 = new JTable(dataForSecondTable,columnNames);

        JPanel panelForTable = new JPanel();
        JPanel panelOther = new JPanel();

        add(panelForTable,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(panelOther,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        //table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        panelForTable.add(table);
        panelOther.add(getContentPane().add(scrollPane1));
        panelOther.add(button);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Table();
    }
}
```